# Install DocShare for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, eclipse-ecf

I am trying to install DocShare for Eclipse. I installed the ECF but how do I install the DocShare plugin?

I know this is a repeat question but the other one wasn't answered and was posted nearly a year ago.

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to use [Saros](http://www.saros-project.org) instead. It allows me to real-time collaborate easily and is easy to install. I will use this instead of DocShare.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following will allow for installing `ECF Docshare` after the ECF has been installed from the marketplace.

- In Help-->Install New Software, add a new Site. The URL will be (as taken from http://www.eclipse.org/ecf/downloads.php, indicating that as of 2017-05-18 3.13.7 was the latest): http://download.eclipse.org/rt/ecf/3.13.7/site.p2
  [image: Eclipse Add Repository]
- Then expand "Other ECF Features". In that section you will find "ECF Docshare" and "ECF Docshare developer Resources". Select the first and possibly the second. [image: ECF Docshare in ECF Features]
- Then select "Next" and it will resolve the dependencies and install.

As to whether it still works or how to use it, I'm not certain. But there was development on it just 3 months ago according to [the information ag the Eclipse ECF git repo](https://github.com/eclipse/ecf/tree/master/framework/bundles/org.eclipse.ecf.docshare), so it might be OK.

There is some information (no idea how current) at: [ECF/DocShre Plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/ECF/DocShare_Plugin).

Comment: I installed the entire package of Other ECF Features as you said. However, I did have some problems. It notified me that EITHER the XMPP provider package or the ECF SDK for Eclipse could be installed at a time. I installed one, and then uninstalled it and then installed the other and neither showed the "Share Editor With..." option. Is there something I'm missing? How do I connect my account with the ECF?